# Unable to fetch certain columns out of a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse certain fields out of a table from a webpage. The fields I'm after are within the headers `Home` and `Handicap`. I can get the content within the header `Home` but can't get the content within the header `Handicap`. How may I get it?

This is my try so far:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League/2018-2019/36.html")
time.sleep(3) #intentional delay to let the webpage load it's content
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for items in soup.select('table#Table3 tr'):
    name = items.find_all("td")[2].text
    # stat = items.find_all("td")[5].text  #this is not working
    print(name)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two rows are just headers. To get values you need to iterate over all rows *excluding first two*:

```
for items in soup.select('table#Table3 tr')[2:]:
    name = items.find_all("td")[2].text
    stat_ft = items.find_all("td")[5].text
    stat_ht = items.find_all("td")[6].text
    print(name, stat_ft, stat_ht)
```

Comment: Always perfect. Thanks sir @Andersson for your wonderful solution.